# Numerical Fourier transform

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I am having issues trying to numerically Fourier transform the following function
\begin{equation}
f(x) =\frac{1}{x^6}\sqrt{4m^2x^2+x^4}\log\biggm(\frac{2m^2 + x^2 + \sqrt{4m^2x^2+x^4}}{2m^2}\biggm)
\end{equation}
where we can take $x>0$ and $m>0$. I am using the Fourier series package provided by Mathematica. The core issue of the function is the $1/x^6$ (or just the $1/x^5$) pole that I attempted to regularize with the substitution $1/x^5\rightarrow 1/(x^3(x^2+a)$ in the limit that $a\rightarrow 0$. With this, I attempted to use the NMaximize command on $a$ which did not work. For simplicity, we can also take $m=1$ and using the Maximize function, but again it arrives to "non-numerical values..."

I don't know much (well really anything) about numerical analysis of functions, so hopefully there is a way to make this Numerical Fourier transform nice.

I would like to also Fourier transform this function as a whole, but Mathematica does not provide anything (it just outputs the same as I put in).

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

EDIT: here is my raw code:

```
NMaximize[With[{m = 1}, NFourierTransform[(Sqrt[4*m^2 + Q^2]*Log[1 + (Q*(Q + Sqrt[4*m^2 + Q^2]))/(2*m^2)])/(Q^2*(Q^4 + a)), Q, 0.01]], a]
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @azerbajdzan I believe that is what you want (with it fully simplified).

Comment: Evidently `NFourierTransform` does not work even with much simpler functions but I am not an expert on it.

Comment: Your function inside "NFourierTransform" contains a symbolic constant: a. N-functions can not work with symbolic variables. Further, even if the symbolic constant is removed, the FourierTransfrom does not work, because your function is not L1 (absolute) integrable.

Comment: I don't think the Mathematica expression is consistent with your typeset function.  I suggest that providing a Mathematica version of `f[x]` would be the most effective way of attracting help.

Comment: This Fourier transform exists in neither  the usual sense nor the sense of distributions and `FourierTransform[Sqrt[4  m^2*x^2 + x^4]   Log[1 + x^2 + Sqrt[4  m^2*x^2 + x^4]/(2  m^2)]/(x^6), x, s,   Assumptions -> m > 0]` returns the input.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if this helps but we can do numerical Fourier transforms by using `Fourier`.
Let's start by making your function and looking at what happens as your as we go towards the pole.

```
 ClearAll[f];
    f[x_, m_, a_] := (
     Sqrt[4 m^2 + x^2] 
     Log[1 + (x (x + Sqrt[4 m^2 + x^2]))/(2 m^2)])/(
     x (a + x^4))
    Limit[f[x, m, a], x -> 0]

(*  2/a  *)
```

So the limit goes as 2/a independent of m
Now let's look at your function for a particular value of a and a range of values of m.

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[Table[f[x, m, 0.1], {m, {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50}}]], {x,
   0, 25}]
```

[image]

The values of m don't make much of a difference around the pole.

We can now sample your function and take the numerical Fourier transform

```
sf = Join[{2/0.1}, 
  Table[f[x, 1, 0.1], {x, 25/2048., 25, 25/(2048. - 1)}]]; ff = 
 Fourier[sf];
ListLogPlot[Abs[ff[[1 ;; 1024]]], Joined -> True]
ListLinePlot[Arg[ff[[1 ;; 1024]]]]
```

[image]

[image]

I am only taking half of the Fourier transform because the second half is symmetric (real part) or antisymmetric (imaginary part)

You want to find out what happens as you vary the parameter `a`. Next I take several values of `a` and look at how the Fourier transform varies.

```
sf = Table[
   Fourier[Join[{2/a}, 
      Table[f[x, a, 0.1], {x, 25/2048., 25, 25/(2048. - 1)}]]][[1 ;; 
      1024]],
   {a, 0.01, 0.5, 0.01}];
ListPlot3D[Log@Abs[sf], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Obviously you want to see what happens as `a` goes to zero. This would require numerical analytic continuation. I am building a function to do this but its not ready yet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: All that is built on the sand. This Fourier transform exists in neither the usual sense nor the sense of distributions and `FourierTransform[Sqrt[4  m^2*x^2 + x^4]   Log[1 + x^2 + Sqrt[4  m^2*x^2 + x^4]/(2  m^2)]/(x^6), x, s,   Assumptions -> m > 0]` returns the input.

Comment: I don't understand your comment "All this is built on the sand".  Your function, once sampled, has a numerical Fourier transform and I have calculated it for a range of values of your parameter `a`. It probably does not have a function that can be expressed as an algebraic formula -if that is what you were hoping for.

Comment: The question begins with "I am having issues trying to numerically Fourier transform the following function..."

Comment: You want the numerical Fourier transform. By sampling your function I have given you  2048 terms in the Fourier series which approximates the continuous Fourier transform.

Comment: If Fourier transform does not exist, then numerical Fourier transform does not exist too,  You produce a certain lst of real numbers, making use `Sqrt[4  m^2*x^2 + x^4]   Log[1 + x^2 + Sqrt[4  m^2*x^2 + x^4]/(2  m^2)]/(x^6)`. After that you apply `Fourier` to this list. I repeat all that wishful  thinking  is built on the sand. That's all.

Comment: I have done what you suggest and used your regularisation.  With your regularisation the function exists and I have plotted it for various values of m. I have then looked at its Fourier expansion as you suggest.  Of course the Fourier representation is complex so I have looked at the absolute part. You could also look at the argument or the real and imaginary or the cos terms or the sin terms. The issue you have is to work out the form of your function as your term a goes to zero. In mathematical terms this means what generalised function or system of poles will represent your function.

Comment: The process of removing the regularisation and finding the form of the function is called by mathematicians numerical analytical continuation. So nothing I have been giving you is built on sand...

Comment: Can you give an accessible and solid reference to  that claim? I prefer arguments over empty words.

Comment: Here are a couple on numerical analytic continuation. First an old one from (1965) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2949813 and a very readable new one (2023) https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13160-023-00599-2.  There are plenty more references where you can learn about this area, just google. Finally, this is a respectable site where people try to be helpful. We don't go round accusing people of talking rubbish.

Comment: Here is abstract of the second item "Let $f$ be an analytic function on a simply-connected compact continuum $E$ of the complex $z$-plane. This might be an interval of the real line, where f might be real analytic. How can we calculate good estimates of the analytic continuation of $f$ to other points $z\in\mathbb{C}$ ? How can we estimate the locations of real or complex singularities of $f$?

Comment: We review both the theory and the practice of some existing methods for these problems and propose that excellent results can be obtained from the computation of rational approximations of f by the AAA algorithm. In the case of analytic functions of two or more variables, the rational approximations are applied along line segments or other analytic arcs".  Are you not tired?

Comment: We review both the theory and the practice of some existing methods for these problems and propose that excellent results can be obtained from the computation of rational approximations of f by the AAA algorithm. In the case of analytic functions of two or more variables, the rational approximations are applied along line segments or other analytic arcs". I don't see any regularisation of the Fourier transform here.  Are you not tired?